# How to view the underlying code in an Excel Workbook?

Tags: excel

I have gotten an excel workbook from a colleague.  It will help to view the underlying code he uses to produce the tab that contains charts.

Do you know how to see the underlying function in an Excel page that is designed to produce charts? I have heard that saving the whole file to XML format is the first step but maybe not.  I have "Some features in your workbook might be lost if you save it as XML Spreadsheet 200"  So, I assume that this means that the functionality used to produce the charts will be gone"

When I was writing this question just now, stackoverflow showed the post "Protecting the code in an Excel Workbook?"  I hope this does not mean that possibly the other programmer has blocked this.

Comment: Step one: is this file an `XLSM`? If it is saved as `XLSX` then there is no VBA code.

Comment: Then there is no VBA code. Unhide the hidden tabs and look at the formulas

Comment: It is an XLSX file. I have unhidden a couple of tabs but they only show more data.  It looks like output from some calculations.  I do not see any formulas.  When I click on the chart, I see the option to see "Select Data Source" but here I only see information for Horizontal Axis Lables and Legend.  Just cosmetic, not the forumlas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Right click on chart
2. Click `Select Data`
3. View `Chart Data Range`
4. View `Series` or `Category` by selecting on desired fields and click `Edit`

Once you find the desired range, you will then have to follow the formulas.

[image]

Comment: You beat me to it.  I was about to provide virtually the exact same answer.

Answer (score 0):

Allstar Exposure
Income Statement
For the Month Ended [Month/Year]

|  |  | Amount ($) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Sales |  | 410,000 |
| Cost of Goods Sold |  | 0 |
| Gross Profit |  |  |
|  |  |  |
| Operating Expenses |  |  |
| Sales Commissions |  | 50,000 |
| Technology Costs |  | 75,000 |
| R&D Costs |  | 200,000 |
| Selling Expenses |  | 10,000 |
| Administrative Expenses |  | 35,000 |
| Total Operating Expenses |  |  |
|  |  |  |
| Net Income |  |  |